# Given a cumulative distribution function of the form $P(X\leq x) = 1- e^{-\lambda x^3}$, is there a way to represent it using an exponential?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Given a cumulative distribution function of the form $P(X\leq x) = 1- e^{-\lambda x^3}$, is there any way to represent it in terms of an exponential or any other distribution? I've thought about exponentials, but don't know how to deal with the cubed term. Thanks!

Comment: Exponential Distributions have cdf of the form $1- e^{\lambda x}$. Maybe you can play with gamma distributions?

Comment: karmanaut is right and this integral most definitely does not equal to one when integrated over the sample space. You might be able to define a new random variable $Z=X^3$ as a function of $X$, and substitute that for $X^3$...?

Comment: @genap It's a CDF, interpreted for nonnegative values of $x$ (for negative values one would assume the result should be just zero of course). It doesn't need to be integrated.

Comment: @Ian I was thinking about a possible PDF for this given CDF. I should have been more clear about that; my apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Let $W$ have exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$.  Let $X=W^{1/3}$. Then if $x\gt 0$, we have $\Pr(X\le x)=\Pr(W^{1/3}\le x)=\Pr(W\le x^3)=1-e^{-\lambda x^3}$.

Answer (score 1):

The cumulative distribution function $$F_{X}(x) = 1-e^{-\lambda x^3}\text{, }x \geq 0$$
implies that $X$ follows a (two-parameter) [Weibull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Distribution_function) distribution. Using the parametrization in the link, the [density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Definition) is $f\left(x, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\lambda}},3\right)$.

As Andre has shown, if $Y$ is exponential with mean $\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$, $X = Y^{1/3}$ has this distribution function. See also [this link](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/ExponentialWeibull.pdf).